# Understanding of multigrid method

Tags: numerical-methods, multigrid

I am struggling understanding Multi Grid methods. I would like to develop an example of two-grid methods applying to f.e. this equation:

$$-u''(x)+u(x)=x, \qquad u(0)=u(1)=0$$

I am able to create a SLAE for this equation: $$Ax=b$$ and solve it with Jacobi method:
$$
x_{i}^{(k+1)}={\frac {1}{a_{ii}}}\left(b_{i}-\sum _{j\neq i}a_{ij}x_{j}^{(k)}\right),\quad i=1,2,\ldots ,n
$$

But I can't figure out how to solve it using two-grid approach?

Comment: That particular equation is easy to solve exactly.

Comment: I know but on this particular simple example I hope it will be more easy to understand multigrid method

Comment: Are you trying to convert to an equation $(y_1; y_2)' = A(y_1;y_2) + (0;-x)$ for a matrix $A$? With $y_1=u$ and $y_2=u'$?

Comment: I do not understand your notation

Comment: Define $y_1(x)=u(x)$ and $y_2(x)=u'(x)$.  Then $y_1'(x) = y_2(x)$ and $$y_2'(x)= u''(x) = u(x)-x = y_1(x)-x$$ So we can write a matrix ODE $$\frac{d}{dx} (y_1(x);y_2(x)) = A(y_1(x);y_2(x)) + (0;-x)$$ with $2 \times 2$ matrix $A = [0 \: 1; 1 \: 0]$

Comment: Oh, ok. But all in all I would like to try direct multigrid approach without simplification for particular problem

Comment: I found the answer to [understanding-high-and-low-frequency-eigenmodes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2629649/understanding-high-and-low-frequency-eigenmodes) (for the Laplace equation) nice and clear.